# Open oneself before asking question?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, quotations

Si.. How can I phrase or **quote** the below sentence in a better meaningful way

> *"You have to open up about yourself first (like introduce self or answer the question asked by the other person or **to know him first**) so that the other person is comfortable with talking to him about his issues or personal life."*

Much like talking to a therapist. The patient wants to know about the doctor (anything). Why I refer the therapist and the patient here as an example, is because the other person is the one who is offering the help and the patient can discuss anything with the therapist.

---

**Edit:**
I am really sorry for the confusion. Seems like everyone is taking it in the wrong way. What I actually want is to replace the above highlighted sentence with one short sentence like a quote in a polite way. Like "**Open oneself before asking**" would this be the appropriate one or is there any other phrase or quote.

Comment: The phrase "*open up about yourself*" in that context communicates your intent. What's the connection you're trying to draw between that and the two other words you're asking about? If you're not trying to draw a connection there, it (*cf* combining words) should be asked as another question, including background etc as you have nicely done for this question. It would help, though, if you could explain why you feel that "open up" isn't a "meaningful" expression of the idea you're trying to communicate.

Comment: What is the _context_ of the sentence (where do you wish to use it?), and what is your _objective_?

Comment: What does "loud-mouthed" and "wiseacre" have to do with _opening up_? Two diiferent questions, perhaps?

Comment: @Lawrence how can better phrase or quote it in order to used it during written conversation. CF is not related.

Comment: @Mark Worthen how can better phrase or quote it in order to used it during written conversation.

Comment: @Cascabel Yes, separate questions

Comment: Then please ask separate questions.

Comment: @OnePunchMan "open up" seems fine. Why do you think it's not 'meaningful', as you put it?

Comment: @Cascabel Sorry, removed..

Comment: @Lawrence Really sorry about the confusion, please see the edit

Comment: @OnePunchMan I've edited the formatting, there's no space on the inside of brackets or speech marks :)

Comment: @OnePunchMan I've read your edit, but I still don't know what you consider 'unmeaningful' about the phrase. Please elaborate. Note that proofreading is [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site unless you explain what specifically you're finding problematic about the text. Saying that you want something "meaningful" doesn't help - you have to say *why* the existing text is *not* meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

*Self-disclosure promotes openness.*

- You can replace 'promotes' with synonyms such as 'facilitates', 'encourages', or 'furthers'.
- And you can substitute 'self-disclosure', 'risk-taking', 'open communication', or 'frank dialogue' for 'openness'.

A metaphorical expression that communicates the concept:

*Self-disclosure is contagious.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your full intentions but I will help you modify the phrasing so it's grammatically correct using the context I can gather. It sounds to me like you are writing a piece for a therapist about how to deal with patients? Or something of that nature? If that is the case I would change it as follows:

> You must open up about yourself right from the start as this will create
>   a rapport with your patient. For example, answer questions they ask
>   you, tell them about yourself, your life, personal details. Get to
>   know them. This will be very important in allowing them to get
>   comfortable speaking with you about deeper, more intimate,
>   personal issues.

I hope that helps? Please ask a separate question for the other words.

Comment: Please see the edit, really sorry about the confusion.